# DNS stops working after few minutes on WiFi

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, dns

I have rather strange problem.

My Windows stops resolving DNS names after few minutes of connection (Wi-Fi). I need to restart my connection to fix it. It happens randomly.

After few minutes of perfectly good internet connection I'm getting "dns_probe_finished_nxdomain" error in chrome and most apps that rely on DNS are not working.

I tried setting Google DNS and also using provided DNSs from ISP. The same effect.

I tried running ping command on my current DNS server and it never stops responding (even when Windows decides to stop using it for some reason).

I have new installation of Windows 10 on my Dell inspiron Laptop. This Laptop has no problems what so ever when using cable.

There are only few networks that it has problem with. Unfortunately one of those networks is my parents home network and I'm stuck here for some time.

I'm willing to run any diagnostics tool you throw at me and give you logs. I really need it fixed and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem I am having a similar issue.
http://superuser.com/questions/1043308/internet-stops-working-after-few-minutes