# Internet stops working after few minutes

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, internet, wireless-router

My internet stops working after few minutes and have to disconnect and then reconnect to wifi to make it work.

This issue is only with my laptop other devices mobile/tablet/pc works fine with the same wifi

My internet setup is like this

> MODEM ==> (via lan)  NETGEAR  ===> NETIS (Connected to Netgear wirelessly)

My laptop Internet works fine with netis wifi. But when its connected to Netgear wifi it shows different errors like

```
Your are not online
Dns probe finish ..
etc...
```

Previously with same laptop and Netgear router i was having similar issue it stops working after few minutes and have to reconnect.

I figured out and resolve that issue.. if netgear channel is set to below 5 it doesn't work and its above 5 it work fine..

For few weeks this settings resolved my issue but now i am having same issue and changing channel doesn't work

Currently my router is set to channel 6

This problem is similar to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1012503/dns-stops-working-after-few-minutes-on-wifi). But i am facing other issue that are listed above.

I have tried uninstalling/installing drivers from Device Manger and still same issue.

I am not able to find official vendor driver. (Vendor providing drivers for Linux system and i am on windows 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either a dodgy driver or wireless card is the issue here. Few things I'd try:

1. Try installing another OS  (sounds like you're using Linux, download and install a copy of Windows and install the latest drivers for your wireless card). Then use your laptop as normal and see if the issue persists.
2. If you can, try using a USB/expansion wireless adapter, using it as your primary wireless card. Again, check to see if you're still experiencing the issue.

Comment: I am on windows 10.